# $f: X \to Y$ is onto implies $f: \mathcal P(X) \to \mathcal P(Y)$ is onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $B \in \mathcal P(Y)$. Then $B \subseteq Y.$ Since $f$ is onto, for any $y \in B$, there's an $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = y.$ And so $f^{-1}(B) \not = \varnothing$.

Now, can I just say for any $B \in \mathcal P(Y)$, we can find $A \in \mathcal P(X)$, namely $A = f^{-1}(B)$ with $f^{-1}(B) \mapsto B$? Or do we have to explicitly construct $A$? How do we do that if it's the latter?

Comment: But you have already explicitly constructed $A$, namely $A := f^{-1}(B)$. The inclusion $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subseteq B$ holds always, and the other holds because $f$ is onto (can you see why?).

Comment: Please make the body of your MSE questions self-contained. Don't rely on the title to convey important information. As for the mathematics, if $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$, then $f$ is not a function from ${\cal P}(X)$ to ${\cal P}(Y)$, although it does induce a function of that type. And the induced function is onto iff $f$ is onto (by noting that $f(f^{-1}(B)) = B$ for any $B \subseteq Y$ and that $f(\{x\}) = \{f(x)\}$ - you don't need the last bit).